# Second page of pagination link is sending to original page in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

[image]I have a form for searching data on search.blade.php (url :/search) and sending result to another view on the same URL.
when I click on the 2nd link of Pagination Link bar(2 in the image) then it redirects from /search to /search?page=2 and no data display.

```
$users=   DB::table('user')->select('first_name','last_name')->where('city',$city)->groupby('user')->paginate(5);
return view('search_result',['users' => $users]);
```

Comment: With the code you provided we can not help you. The remaining part of the controller is missing, in particular when $city is assigned.

Comment: without pagination this code is working fine, only problem in pagination.

Comment: The problem may not be pagination itself

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to render the links in your blade file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use group by for pagination.